# Rails - Associated field not working as expected for an external table.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am connecting to an external database with rails. I have an opportunities table that has a       field

If I use the following code, I get the company name.

```
<% company_id = opportunity.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId %>
<% @company = CrmTable::Company.where("Comp_CompanyId = ?", company_id) %>
<% @company.each do |company|%>
    <td>
      <%= company.Comp_Name %>

    </td>
<% end %>
```

However, based on what I have done with associations with Rails databases, I thought I could do

```
<% company_id = opportunity.Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId %>
<% @company = CrmTable::Company.where("Comp_CompanyId = ?", company_id) %>
<%= @company.Comp_Name %>
```

When I try that, I get an error of

```
   NoMethodError in Searches#show
Showing C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development/app/views/shared/_opportunity_list.html.erb where line #56 raised:

undefined method `Comp_Name' for #<Company::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xa734738>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/searches/show.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/product_development

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/shared/_opportunity_list.html.erb:56:in `block in _app_views_shared__opportunity_list_html_erb__1021919415_87714420'
app/views/shared/_opportunity_list.html.erb:29:in `each'
app/views/shared/_opportunity_list.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_shared__opportunity_list_html_erb__1021919415_87714420'
app/views/searches/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_searches_show_html_erb__1026643635_104558460'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"180"}
```

If I do a @company.inspect, I see the following for the id corresponding to the current opportunity

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Company Comp_CompanyId: 7, Comp_PrimaryPersonId: 7, Comp_PrimaryAddressId: 13, Comp_PrimaryUserId: 35, Comp_Name: "XXX CORPORATION", Comp_Type: "Customer", Comp_Status: "Active", . . .
```

If I do `Company Last<%= @current_company.last %>`, I get Company Last#`<Company:0x9103c50>`

CrmTable.rb contains

```
class Opportunity < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Opportunity"
  belongs_to :users, class_name: 'CrmUser', foreign_key:  :Oppo_AssignedUserId
  belongs_to :person, class_name:  'Person', foreign_key: :Oppo_PrimaryPersonId
  belongs_to :company, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: :Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId
end

class Company < CrmTable
  self.table_name = "Company"
  has_many :opportunities
  alias_attribute 'company_name','Comp_Name'
end
```

Again, I can't understand why I have to walk through the company records vice using opportunity.company.Comp_Name

I'm not sure if the capitalization is causing a problem. However that is the result of the way the external table is designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @company = CrmTable::Company.where("Comp_CompanyId = ?", company_id) %>
```

returns a collection(Array of CrmTable::Company).  If you want to call Comp_name on each item you can do

```
@company.map(&:Comp_name)
```

but obviously you would want to rename the variable to companies and move forward accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @company.each do |company|%>
    <td>
      <%= company.Comp_Name %>

    </td>
<% end %>
```

Here `@company` is the array of the company objects. If you are expecting object then you should use `first` on the `@company`. it will return an object.

```
<% @company = CrmTable::Company.where("Comp_CompanyId = ?", company_id).first %>
```

Or

```
<% @company = CrmTable::Company.find_by_Comp_CompanyId(company_id) %>
 <% if @company %>
   <%= @company.Comp_Name %>
  <% end %>
```